# Impute values in np.arange function from the comma separated values present in dataframe column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe column

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["X","5,7,7,9"],["Y","20,30,32,48"]],columns=["type","range"])
```

```
type    range
X       5,7,7,9
Y       20,30,32,48
```

I want to impute the above values in np.arange() function such that first 2 values should come in 'min' range of a particular type and the next 2 values should come in 'max' range.

**Expected output**

```
X_limits['min'] = np.arange(5,7)
X_limits['max'] = np.arange(7,9)
Y_limits['min'] = np.arange(20,30)
Y_limits['max'] = np.arange(32,48)
```

Where X_limits = {} and Y_limits = {} are empty dictionaries.
How to do it in python?

Comment: What is `X_limits` and `Y_limits` supposed to be?

Comment: empty dictionary

Comment: Those are strings - you need to split them and convert to integers.